# Is there a "strncopy_to_user" function in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm working on a simple system call in the Linux kernel (v4.0) for a homework assignment. I've copied a string from user space to kernel space using [`strncopy_from_user`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re252.html), modified it, and now want to copy it back.

Is there a `strncopy_to_user`? Or do I just need to use [`copy_to_user`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h?v=4.0#L723)? And if the latter is the case, I'd be curious to know why one exists but not the other.

Comment: If it is not in [uaccess.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h), then it does not exist. Probably because it was found not that useful when was implemented.

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- sounds like an answer to me. Write it up as such and I'll accept it -- thank you!!

Comment: @EugeneSh., this is **BS**, try to use `git grep` next time. `strndup_user()` is a good start.

Comment: @0andriy This function is to duplicate a string *from* user space. The OP is asking about duplication *to* user space (BTW, not even a duplication, but copying to existing buffer).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay, let me be clear. First your sentence is simply wrong. Either second mine (with regards to the question). So, back to the topic what exactly the problem OP tries to solve? `copy_to_user()` does everything they need AFAIU.

Comment: @0andriy First sentence is wrong, I agree (actually the first part of the first sentence, as it actually doesn't exist). The OP is interested in copying a null-terminated buffer into a user space without the hassle to pass it's length. It is solvable by using `copy_to_user` and `strlen` or similar, hence the second sentence.

Comment: When someone got the string from somewhere the length is already known.

Comment: @0andriy is correct. strncopy_from_user copies a string of unknown length up to the NUL. Coping back the length is know so you can just copy_to_user N+1 bytes.

Comment: @stark - Makes sense. Thank you!